# Setting textbox textmode to number not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hello the below Javascript code wont run when i set asp grid view textbox to `TextMode="Number"`

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id*=gridpur]input[type=text][id*=txt]").on('keyup mouseup', (function(e) {
        var unitprice = $(e.target).closest('tr').find("input[type=text][id*=txtUnitprice]").val();
        var quantity = $(e.target).closest('tr').find("input[type=text][id*=txtQuantity]").val();
        var total = unitprice * quantity;
        $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=lblTotal]").text(total);
    }));
});
```

**Markup:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridpur" CssClass="table table-bordered text-nowrap" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product_Name" HeaderText="Product Name" SortExpression="Product_Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Price" SortExpression="UnitPrice">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitprice" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitprice" min="0" TextMode="Number" step="any" Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice") %>' CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Unit Price" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="UnitPrice">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" CssClass="form-control" min="0" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" min="0" TextMode="Number" step="any" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Quantity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Amount" SortExpression="UnitPrice">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the API, textmode is for setting the TEXT mode of the control to **single-line**, **multiline**, or **password**. In HTML, a TEXT box always contains TEXT, but can be configured as a single-line textbox, a multi-line textbox or a password textbox. In .NET, textmode allows you to determine which variation of the HTML textbox the server should send in its response to the client.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode(v=vs.110).aspx